# In OpenGL ES, can multiple programs have the same VBO used and bound to their attributes?

Tags: opengl-es, vbo, glsles, vertex-buffer-objects

I have two programs which I am switching between. I loaded my position data up in a VBO and then set up my vertex attribute arrays for my first program. When I switch to the second program and attempt to set up my vertex attribute arrays using the same data, it fails to draw. If I make a second buffer using the exact same code however, and I use it for the second program, they both draw fine. I was wondering if someone might clarify the rules of sharing these VBO's between programs as I'd rather not have two buffers unless they are needed.

Comment: Absolutely. Vertex setup is completely orthogonal to what program is bound. As long as the attribute locations match between the programs, you could even use the same VAO.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - I am very much at a loss as to why I would be able to use one buffer instead of the other when this is the only difference? I will continue testing and post here if I find otherwise

Comment: @RetoKoradi - I found a complex bug in my application that was leading to this condition. You are correct in your statement that this is possible to have multiple programs using the same VBO.

Comment: Can you post an answer explaining what caused it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple programs can be bound to the same VBO with no problem. My issue ended up being with another part of my program loading a separate VBO which was missing some of the vertices and had nothing to do with the use of two programs.